# Accounting for zeros in Time Series data

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

Hi I am transforming my current data set into time series by dividing it into weeks and counts for each week. Currently the weeks where the counts are zero its omitting in the data set for example. Below is the example data set. I want to include all the weeks with counts zero as well. How do i transform it using dplyr.

2013-10-6  1
2014-08-03 1
2014-10-12 1

Comment: One option would be to create a list of dates you want included and join it back to the summarized data frame.

Comment: following on @cardinal40 comment, you could generate a sequence of all dates between your min and max dates and do an outer join on that. if you want a more concrete answer you'll need to provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

**1) dplyr** Assuming the input is `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end right join `DF` to a data frame of weeks and then replace NA values with zero.  In the data frame in the Note at the end `value` is integer but if it is double in your application then use 0 in place of 0L.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
   right_join(data.frame(date = seq(first(.$date), last(.$date), 7))) %>%
   mutate(value = coalesce(value, 0L))
```

**2) zoo** Since this is a time series many calculations can be simplified by using a time series representation.  Converting to zoo object `z` we can use this one-liner which converts from zoo to ts and back which has the effect of inserting NA values.  Since ts class cannot represent dates directly we use aggregate to convert back to Date and then na.fill to replace the NAs with 0.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF, frequency = 7)

na.fill(aggregate(as.zoo(as.ts(z)), as.Date, c), 0)
```

This could also be written as:

```
library(magrittr)

z %>% as.ts %>% as.zoo %>% aggregate(as.Date, c) %>% na.fill(0)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "2013-10-6 1
2014-08-03 1
2014-10-12 1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, col.names = c("date", "value"))
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date)
```

Comment: Thank You for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `complete` and `full_seq` from the `tidyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(V1 = as.Date(V1)) %>%
  complete(V1 = full_seq(V1, period = 7), fill = list(V2 = 0))
dat2
# # A tibble: 54 x 2
#    V1            V2
#    <date>     <dbl>
#  1 2013-10-06     1
#  2 2013-10-13     0
#  3 2013-10-20     0
#  4 2013-10-27     0
#  5 2013-11-03     0
#  6 2013-11-10     0
#  7 2013-11-17     0
#  8 2013-11-24     0
#  9 2013-12-01     0
# 10 2013-12-08     0
# # ... with 44 more rows
```

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "'2013-10-6' 1
'2014-08-03' 1
                  '2014-10-12' 1",
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```